# Purchasing meat during the 9 days

Tags: meat, nine-days

I understand the prohibition on eating meat during the nine days, but is one allowed to still purchase meat for later consumption outside of the 9 days.

Comment: Crudler, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly. At least one shabbos will occur during the Nine Days, and meat is permitted for consumption then. Until refrigeration was invented, eating meat on Shabbos meant -- well yes they had other preservation methods, but most likely people would be buying it during the Nine Days too.

Similarly someone could be making a *seudas mitzva* and permitted to eat meat; so he could buy the meat whenever is convenient -- or I could buy the meat for him, and so on.

Comment: +1, but it doesn't address buying meat for after the nine days (which, I admit, wasn't directly asked about). I'm almost sure that's permitted too, but I have no source at the moment.